# R retrieving strings with sub: Why this does not work?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract parts of strings. The string is:

```
> (x <- 'ab/cd efgh "xyz xyz"')
> [1] "ab/cd efgh \"xyz xyz\""
```

Now, I would like first to extract the first part:

```
> # get "ab/cd efgh"
> sub(" \"[/A-Za-z ]+\"","",x)
[1] "ab/cd efgh"
```

But I don't succeed in extracting the second part:

```
> # get "xyz xyz"
> sub("(\"[A-Za-z ]+\")$","\\1",x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "ab/cd efgh \"xyz xyz\""
```

What is wrong with this code?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You have to match the whole string: `sub(".*(\"[A-Za-z ]+\")$","\\1",x, perl=TRUE)` will work. From the help file: "Elements of character vectors x which are not substituted will be returned unchanged."

Comment: R's tool for extracting matches is `regmatches`, though it's kind of convoluted.

Comment: @lmo Thanks for explaining. Put your comment to the answer so I can give you a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last snippet does not work because you reinsert the whole match back into the result: `(\"[A-Za-z ]+\")$` matches and captures `"`, 1+ letters and spaces, `"` into Group 1 and `\1` in the replacement puts it back.

You may actually get the last part inside quotes by removing all chars other than `"` at the start of the string:

```
x <- 'ab/cd efgh "xyz xyz"'
sub('^[^"]+', "", x)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/Fmlvxl)

The `sub` here will find and replace just once, and it will match the string start (with `^`) followed with 1+ chars other than `"` with `[^"]+` negated character class.

Comment: Thanks for answer and solution.

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work with `sub`, you have to match the whole string. The help file says

> For sub and gsub return a character vector of the same length and with the same attributes as x (after possible coercion to character). Elements of character vectors x which are not substituted will be returned unchanged (including any declared encoding).

So to get this to work with your regex, pre-pend the sometimes risky catchall ".*"

```
sub(".*(\"[A-Za-z ]+\")$","\\1",x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "\"xyz xyz\""
```